# CKEditor wysiwyg working in local not working in server

Tags: web, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor. when i work in localhost (in my pc) its working fine in formating and image upload.but when i work with it at server it formating and image upload is not working.

for ex. - if i formate font with some style and color and size its shows all effect front side on local but when i use same style same font and same color its not shows any formating or image on its front side.

for save that text i used mysql_real_escape_string() function i also tried mysql_escape_string() but both are working in local only not on server. :S

for image upload its path gose wrong into database so its not showing front side.

for ex.

local path - 
(`http://localhos/exo/uploads/24ysjdh.jpg`)

server path - (`http://mysite.in/%22/uploads/image/11/2qiz714.jpg/%22`) (in this url %22 is making problem)

i dont know why the editor is working in local and not working in server. :S i faced this unique problem first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP MagicQuotes could be causing this. It seems like there is something wrong in the /uploads/image/11/2qiz714.jpg. There are extra /" wrapped around it is changing to /%22

```
/%22/uploads/image/11/2qiz714.jpg/%22
```

It is probably in code that generates the path. Are MagicQuotes turned on or off? Can you paste piece of your code that creates this path? once you find it double check that all the " and escaped /" are proper.